# How can I make a text field for a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html, textfield, redirect, onsubmit

I THINK i have managed to write a script. I just can not make a textfield in HMTL to enter the missing data. It it supposed to receive the keyword from a text field on submit click and navigate to the URL.

I have tried multiple ways of forms and everything. Should have installed VB.net and this would have been done in 5 min.

```js
function urlMaker(keyword) {
  var base = "https://www.example.com/list.php?q=";
  var ending = "&dhd=1&hdd=low&dtt=list";
  var url;
  url = base + keyword + ending;
  window.location.assign(url);
}
```

In short words:
I need to know how to create a HTML page with a textfield and a submit button. When I submit it takes the text from the field and run the function and feeds it with the keyword from the textfield. When function has ran it redirects browser.

Comment: Sorry, but we'll need more info. What does the above have to do with a textfield? What is the end result?

Comment: yeah, it would be great if you could share your html as well.

Comment: I need to know how to create a HTML page with a textfield and a submit button. When I submit it takes the text from the field and run the function and feeds it with the keyword from the textfield. When function has ran it redirects browser

Comment: I have tried to many variants of HTML so Im clueless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a form like this.

Just attach a `submit` event-listener to it:

```js
document.querySelector("#search").addEventListener("submit", urlMaker)

function urlMaker(event) {
  let keyword = document.querySelector("#keyword").value;
  let base = "https://www.example.com/list.php?q=";
  let ending = "&dhd=1&hdd=low&dtt=list";
  let url;
  event.preventDefault();
  url = base + keyword + ending;
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

```html
<form id="search">
  <input type="text" id="keyword" />
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hey!! It seems to work when I try the function "Run code snippet. But when trying to implement it in my own HTML i fail. Not working. What am i doing wrong??

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<script>
document.querySelector("#search").addEventListener("submit", urlMaker)

function urlMaker(event) {
  let keyword = document.querySelector("#keyword").value;
  let base = "https://www.example.com/list.php?q=";
  let ending = "&dhd=1&hdd=low&dtt=list";
  let url;
  event.preventDefault();
  url = base + keyword + ending;
  window.location.href = url;
}
</script>


<form id="search">
  <input type="text" id="keyword" />
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Try putting the form over the script tags, then the HTML is loaded before JS tries to attach that eventListener

Comment: OMG THAT WAS CORRECT. You solved it Luca! Thank you!
And THIS is why i hate web programming.

Comment: No problem! Nice I helped you :-) Please mark the question answered, if you feel like it is ;-)

Comment: Yes and I will study the code til I've learnt it. Im no stack exchange leecher